# Drag out to delete item

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

You know that effect when you drag out an item from the dock and that cloud drag cursor appears and when you let go it disappears with a poof effect? Similarly, in Xcode when you drag a breakpoint outside the line number gutter the same happens.

I would like to implement the same effect in my application but can't find the right way.

I have an NSImageView descendant to implement the NSDraggingSource and NSDraggingDestination protocols. I have several instances of this view which allow to drag their content between the others (a copy operation takes place in this scenario, but that's only relevant to show I have drag'n drop implmented and fully working for standard tasks).

Now, when I drag out an image from its view to anywhere (except another view instance) I want to have the delete operation taking place on drop. However the drag operation is fully controlled by the target view. I could manage to make them respond the way I want (even though this would be a lot of work), but it fails completely if I'm dragging outside my application.

If I could get the delete drag operation I could handle this however easily by:

```
- (void)draggedImage: (NSImage *)image
             endedAt: (NSPoint)screenPoint
           operation: (NSDragOperation)operation
{
    if (operation == NSDragOperationDelete) {
        NSRect rect = [self.window convertRectToScreen: [self convertRect: self.frame fromView: nil]];
        NSShowAnimationEffect(NSAnimationEffectPoof, rect.origin, self.bounds.size, nil, nil, NULL);
    }
}
```

I tried already to set the delete cursor like this:

```
- (void)draggingSession: (NSDraggingSession *)session
           movedToPoint: (NSPoint)screenPoint
{
    if (!NSPointInRect(screenPoint, self.window.frame)) {
        [[NSCursor disappearingItemCursor] set];
    }
}
```

(for simplicity this is for the entire windw at the moment). This works as long as I don't hit the desktop or a finder window. In starts flickering, probably because the Finder concurrently sets its own drag cursor. It is completely without effect when I hit the dock. This also happens when I define my own pasteboard data type.

Additionally, any other drop enabled view in my application will still accept my drag data (e.g. NSTextView) which I don't want to happen (I'm writing an NSURL to the dragging pasteboard with a custom scheme).

**Update:**

I've come a few steps further. As Peter already indicated it is essential to handle `draggingSession:sourceOperationmaskForDraggingContext:` which looks so in my code:

```
- (NSDragOperation)       draggingSession: (NSDraggingSession *)session
    sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext: (NSDraggingContext)context;
{
    switch(context) {
        case NSDraggingContextOutsideApplication:
            return NSDragOperationDelete;
            break;

        case NSDraggingContextWithinApplication:
        default:
            return NSDragOperationDelete | NSDragOperationMove;
            break;
    }
}
```

This solves 2 problems: 1) outside the application the drag operation is not accepted at all, 2) it keeps all standard views from accepting this operation too (because NSOutlineView, NSTextView etc. don't handle the given drag operations). Additionally, I created an own pasteboard datatype, but this doesn't seem to be necessary. Still it's clearer to have an own one.

Unfortunately, dropping outside of my NSImageView descendant (both within and outside the application) does not give me NSDragOperationDelete in `draggedImage:endedAt:operation:` (what I specified above) but NSDragOperationNone. Additionally the drag cursor when moving the mouse outside the application is the not-allowed one, not the disappearing-item. So, if someone could solve these two things I'd accept it as answer to my question.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your dragging source's implementation of the `draggingSession:sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext:` method.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a less hacky way to do this, but I can think of one possibility: once the drag begins, create a transparent, borderless window the size of the desktop to be a dummy drag destination. You may need to call `-setIgnoresMouseEvents:` with `NO` to allow it to receive the drop even though it's transparent. You'll also have to set its window level above the menu bar (NSMainMenuWindowLevel + 1) to make sure that drags to the menu bar or Dock are still intercepted by your window.

As a drag destination, this window will have to check if one of your image views is under the cursor. You can use `+[NSWindow windowNumberAtPoint:belowWindowWithWindowNumber:]` to find the window below your transparent overlay window which is under the cursor. Then use `-[NSApplication windowWithWindowNumber:]` to determine if it's one of your app's windows and, if so, call `-[NSView hitTest:]` on its content view (converting the cursor coordinates as appropriate) to find the view. You can then forward `NSDraggingDestination` methods to that view as desired.

Comment: Hmm, I have a 3 monitor setup. Others certainly use a different setting. This means I would have to check all monitors too. Also when you drag out from the dock you still can switch apps with ⌘ + Tab etc. So they definitely don't use a cover-all-window.

Comment: You would need to make your window cover the whole desktop, yes. That's not hard. Just loop over `[NSScreen screens]`, get the `-frame`, and union them together using `NSUnionRect()`. A window at `NSMainMenuWindowLevel` + 1 won't cover the application switcher. I'm not sure in what sense you expect Command-Tab to not work. Also, the Dock doesn't actually allow dropping anywhere else, so maybe it doesn't use real drag-and-drop. Maybe it just uses mouse tracking and sets the cursor. I have a test drag destination app and it doesn't receive `-draggingEntered:` for a drag from the Dock on 10.6.

Comment: Actually, that's an interesting idea. While dragging out from the dock I can do everything with the system that doesn't require a left click (e.g. I can right click, or middle click which goes into Exposé, trigger menu items etc.). Very similar for dragging out breakpoints in XCode. You are very close to earn the bounties. Just give me a working solution in your answer.

Comment: I think, too, that Ken's solution is the correct one. Another hint: If you set the window level of your app's window to dummyWindow.level +1, you probably do not need to check for your own windows. The dragging into them will be done by the system including the dragging destination work.

Comment: BTW: The earlier versions of IB had different windows for top-level objects and windows, so you had to drag from a "window window" to the tlo window. That worked the same way.

Comment: You can't bump up the window level of the visible window without having visible consequences, like your window coming in front of the menu bar or Dock.

Comment: @KenThomases, will you work out a solution which doesn't use the normal drag'n drop procedure? I could do myself, but I have now the bounty pending here...

Comment: Sorry, no. Too busy with work. Thanks for the offer of the bounty but I can't claim it. I hope my suggestions helped, though. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that NSDragOperationDelete only concerns drag/drops targeting the **dock's Trash**, and nothing else.

**NSDragOperationGeneric** should be a better fit.
Be sure not to mix methods, if you're going the 10.7 route, prefer :

```
-(void)draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session endedAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint operation:(NSDragOperation)operation
```

Comment: That's how I do it currently. The problem is that I always get a NSDragOperationNone (except for my own view where I get the drag operations I started with). As I said in another comment, from my observations I really think the dock does not use normal drag/drop but a simple mouse capture like approach. During the "drag" operation you can interact fully with the rest of the system (except left mouse button).

Comment: Yeah, that's entirely possible.  It seems like it a combination of a minimum-timer and distance discrimination, you know to protect from accidental drops. Nothing too fancy

Comment: I just checked, also during a normal drag operation you can right click and open a menu and all that. So now I think rather it's still normal drag'n drop in the dock (didn't expect that, so I never checked). Makes also sense when you consider that you need dd for moving entries in the dock. So we are back to square 1 and need an answer how the dock manages the drag cursor. I guess dragSession:movedToPoint: plays an important role, so it shouldn't be that hard to solve. I just want to get something for my bounty ;-)

Comment: Except, as I noted, if you drag from the Dock to a test app that accepts all types, the test app never gets `-draggingEntered:`.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished implementing something very similar to what you've described. Your code is quite similar to mine with a few exceptions:

Where you use `draggedImage:endedAt:operation:` I'm using `draggingSession:session:endedAt:operation:`. Also, in this method, I do not check the operation as all of my operations are set to `generic`. This is also where I perform the actual delete, so I only show the poof animation if the delete is successful.

In your `draggingSession:session:movedToPoint:`, you may also want to set the `session`'s `animatesToStartingPositionsOnCancelOrFail` to `false` when the point is outside the window (this is also when you set the `disappearingItemCursor`) and set to `true` otherwise. This adds a final touch that once the deletion operation is completed, the dragged image doesn't rebound back to it's originating source location.

As for why you are not seeing the proper cursors, my guess is that you are using a Pasteboard type that other things (Finder, etc.) are willing to accept. I know you said you created your own Pastboard datatypes, but I would double-check that they are being used. When I made my own types, I gained control over the cursor. At least, I've not found anything that contends for my custom type.

Answer (score 0):

**OS X 10.7 or better:**

```
- (void) draggingEnded: (id<NSDraggingInfo>) aInfo {
    /*! Delete the current leaf if it is no longer represented in the subviews. */
    RETURN_IF ( , NSNotFound != [self.visibleLeafs indexOfObject: iSelectedControl.representedObject] );
    iIgnoreLeafsObservation = YES;
    [self.leafs removeObject: iSelectedControl.representedObject];
    iIgnoreLeafsObservation = NO;
}
```

This assumes that you have visually removed the object already. You could also set a flag during draggingEntered: and draggingExited: to indicate if drag session was last inside or outside of self.

In this program, leafs is the actual observed collection while visibleLeafs is a simulated collection of the representedObject of each visible control. Other NSDraggingDestination overloads present what will happen visually before it actually happens.

Comment: Hmm, this code is just a different approach to work around the missing NSDragOperationDelete operation. It doesn't really improve the workaround I have currently.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the following command to make the poof appears at the mouse location:

```
NSShowAnimationEffect(NSAnimationEffectPoof, [NSEvent mouseLocation], NSZeroSize, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

See the [Application Kit Functions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html) for further information.

Comment: I not only did not ask for how to run the poof effect I also have this already in my question.

Comment: @MikeLischke: sorry, I misunderstood your question. Can you be more specific on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hmm, I think I pretty well explain what I'm after. The drag-out-to-remove-effect from the dock is pretty well known and my question is about how to do this in my own app.